# record count based on current date (Today's date)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form in which I enter a record and I have a field that automatically updates with the current date. I would like to add a subform that tells me how many records have been entered "today" based on current date (today's date). I would like it to keep a running total. I am new to asking questions in this format and appreciate any help and understanding.

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: I am using Access 2003. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: what is meant by the error message "Undefined function 'curdate' in expression?  I am obviously missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Again: the sql statement you're trying is outdated as you didn't specify that you are using access back then. Simply have a look at the updated sql statement a second time.

Comment: Why do you need a subform to show a count? DCount would work very well. If you wish to show the records entered, a subform would work using add_date as the link child field and the date textbox name as the link master field.

Comment: note the use of DATE() rather than CURDATE()

Comment: Thank you to all who have responded.  Just a quick not of Thanks. Have been busy taking care of medical issues for my father, but did not want to be ungrateful for all the suggestions presented. Once again, Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For Access:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE add_date BETWEEN DATE() AND DATE()+1;
```

as suggested by [David W. Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9787/david-w-fenton) in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I typed the following:
SELECT count (*)
FROM Monitors
WHERE radd_date>=curdate();
the error message I get is:
Undefined function 'curdate' in expression.
What info am I missing to provide to you?

Comment: You have copied my previous revision which was meant to be for mysql. Try the current one and it should work.

Comment: In other words: it's DATE() in access and not CURDATE()

Comment: I actually got it to run, however the count was "0". I know that for the date of 08/25/09, I have records entered.

Comment: What data type does the column radd_date have in your table? Could you maybe post a dump of the first say 3 rows just so we know how your table looks?

Comment: Allow for a my ignorance.  how do I post a dump of the first 3 rows? The column I Im trying to add is titled Today's Date and Data type is Date/Time, with format as general date. My Table is titled Monitors.

Comment: Well that's odd. Could you check what SELECT DATE(); returns?

Comment: Andre, Thank you for not giving up on me.  how would you write out the statement? I am not sure where I should put SELECT DATE()

Comment: Actually it should be the same place where you currently run the other statement. You then should see what DATE() returns and can compare it to what's stored in your table. Maybe that'll bring you one step closer to why a simple >= comparison isn't working.

Comment: Date() won't match any records where your date field has a time component. If the fields are populated with Now(), they will have times, and won't match. In that case, you your criteria would be BETWEEN Date() AND Date()+1. That's preferable to processing the values to get rid of the time part, as a function can't use an index, whereas the BETWEEN can.

Comment: Thank you to all who have responded.  Just a quick not of Thanks. Have been busy taking care of medical issues for my father, but did not want to be ungrateful for all the suggestions presented. Once again, Many Thanks.

Comment: Now please select the answer that solved your problem by clicking onto the check mark next to the post on the left. You thereby mark your question as answered.